# Is Google Maps API key cached on Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am testing an Android app that uses Google Maps. All went okay. I got the key from Google, put it in my XML, and the grey tiles on the map went away and the actual map appeared. Debug and Release versions run fine on the device. All good.
Now I uninstalled the app from the device, cleaned the project and deliberately corrupted the Google key in my project XML. I reinstall the app and it keeps working fine and the maps appear! I have taken out the Google key and the app still works! What gives? How can my app now run okay without the API key? Is something cached somewhere on the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API key is not cashed, but it is cashed the map.